# Como criar um mapa indoor com a api do google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

Eu tenho um projeto onde quero criar um mapa de uma instalação pública, como um instituto.
 A ideia é abrir a planta do instituto federal numa activity, no Android. Como o aeroporto de guarulhos no google maps
 Pelo o que eu sei, existe o google maps indoor, mas não sei se existe alguma api específica dele para criação de plantas

**Questão**: Eu gostaria de saber se a api do google maps para o Android oferece essa possibilidade e como poderia implementar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É uma pergunta ampla, mas a criação de mapas indoor do google não pode ser feita diretamente por uma API.

Primeiro você precisa enviar a planta do local a partir de um computador para eles aprovarem e depois da aprovação e inserção no Maps, você pode utilizar o local em seu aplicativo, já que ele estará visível para todos. Veja mais [nessa página do Google](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2803784?p=gmm_guidelines&visit_id=1-636425474319698699-3834276328&rd=1) na seção **Carregar uma planta para o Google Maps** para ver os requisitos necessários para enviar uma planta.

O máximo que você pode fazer diretamente pela API é criar polígonos no mapa, mas não será útil para o seu requisito. Ou utilizar o desenho da planta e sobrepor no Maps em uma aplicação, porém isso é conteúdo para outra pergunta.